# Time Dimension: loading date

Tags: business-intelligence

I have a simple question that it may be very easy for those Business Intelligence Architects, but I am struggling to find out the correct way.

I have a fact-table with 2 or more potential date (let's say `opening-date` and `closing-date`) and a measure called `revenue`.

I would like to know the best practice to connect the `Date-Time Dimension` to my `fact table`.

I can see two ways:

1. Connect the fact table  with "loading date":

[image]

With this solution, for each day (therefore, every day)  I will have a record; hence I could have the same record many times in a period.

[image]

2. The second way is to connect the Time Dimension to both `Opening-Date` and `Closing-Date`: 
   [image]

And the ETL should be set up with a date-check, in which if the master key change (the master key should be ID+OD+CD)

[image]

The doubt I have now is the *navigability* of the `fact-table`: in the first case I have all the date, and I can pick up the desired `loading-date` to see the data that I need; instead, in the second case, I have to build a complex join between the `Time-Dimension` and the `fact-table`, paying this join in the Data Visualization tool.

What is the best practice? Is there a best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to implement data modeling technique called ["Role Playing Dimension"](https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/11/role-playing-dimensions/).

Basically, that's option number 2 you mentioned. In my opinion, that's the way to go.

Comment: https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/role-playing-dimension/